# Hive : Multiple In-elements with single subquery

Tags: hive, subquery, in-subquery

I was trying to run a query like this on hive (version 1.2.1) :

```
DELETE  FROM employee as e WHERE  (e.id, e.name) IN ( SELECT emp.id, emp.name FROM employee_final  emp) AND e.sno = 120 ;
```

But since hive doesn't support this construct so I tried this :

```
DELETE FROM employee WHERE 
id  IN (  SELECT emp.id  FROM employee_final AS  emp ) 
AND 
name IN ( SELECT emp.name  FROM employee_final AS  emp      )  
AND e.sno = 120 ;
```

But it seems there is a limitation in hive and it supports just 1 subquery and I am getting an exception like this

> Error Message :  Grammatically incorrect SQL Query :]; nested
>   exception is org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while
>   compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10249]: Line
>   1:185 Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'name': Only 1 SubQuery
>   expression is supported.

What is the most efficient way to handle this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following

1. **through EXISTS** I am not sure about this form for subquery is supported in HIVE.

   ```
   DELETE FROM employee as e WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM employee_final emp where e.id = emp.id and e.name =  emp.name ) AND e.sno = 120 ;
   ```
2. **through CONCAT function**

   ```
   DELETE FROM employee as e WHERE concat (e.id, '#' ,e.name) IN ( SELECT concat (emp.id,'#' ,emp.name) FROM employee_final emp) AND e.sno = 120 ;
   ```

Comment: CONCAT function is useful only in case when 1 of the columns is the primary key of the table. As this will assure uniqueness.

Comment: You don't need primary key for the same